# smart PDF compression in Java (repeated elements)

Tags: java, pdf, compression, pdf-generation, pdfbox

As we are producing PDF reports, we noticed that single image repeated on each page (as we merge more reports together) takes incredible amount of space.

For example :
500 documents each does have 1 page with 100kb image **-> merge operation ->** 500 page document with size 100kb * 500 ~ 50Mb

Is there any library which could compress PDF in a more smart way ?

We are using pdfbox 0.7.3 for PDF merge.

Comment: Itext has a PdfSmartCopy class which tries to recognize duplicate streams, worth a try. But you also might want to check a current PDFBox Version, maybe they have something, too.

Comment: Did you consider upgrading? PDFBox is at version 1.8.1